# Value of $F(r)$ to maximize $\frac{\int_r^1xf(x)dx}{2-F(r)}$

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization

Consider a continuous distribution on $(0,1)$ with probability distribution function $f$ and cumulative distribution function $F$. Define 
$$g(r)=\frac{\int_r^1xf(x)dx}{2-F(r)}$$
and let $r_M\in(0,1)$ be the value of $r$ maximizing $g(r)$. What is an upper bound for $F(r_M)$ in terms of the distribution $F$?

We have $g(0)=\frac{\int_0^1xf(x)dx}{2}$ and $g(1)=0$, so intuitively, for most (not too weird) distributions, $r_M$ shouldn't be too close to $1$, and so $F(r_M)$ should also not be too close to $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let, 
$$\begin{cases} h_1(r)=\int_r^1xf(x)dx \\
h_2(r)=2-F(r) \end{cases}$$

We get derivatives
$$\begin{cases} h_1'(r)=-rf(r) \\
h_2'(r)=-f(r) \end{cases}$$

by definition,
$$g(r)=\frac{h_1(r)}{h_2(r)}$$

the derivative is,
$$g'(r)=\frac{h_1'(r)h_2(r)-h_1(r)h_2'(r)}{h_2^2(r)}$$

To find the maximum,

$$g'(r)=0$$

This gives r_max (minimum is 0),
$$r_{max}-g(r_{max})=0$$

Define a function z, z is continuous.
$$z(r)=r-g(r)$$

because $z(0)=-g(0)\lt 0$ and $z(1)=1$, we know from the intermediate value theorem, there is a root.

when $r=\bar r=\int_0^1 xf(x)dx$, we notice that $z(\bar r)=\frac74\bar r \gt 0$, so we can also conclude that upper bound of $r_{max}$ can be $\bar r$

Comment: How come $r_{max}-g(r_{max})=0$?

Comment: at maximum $r_max$, the derivative equals zero.

Comment: Yes, I understand that $g'(r_{max})=0$, but why is $r_{max}-g(r_{max})=0$? It doesn't follow from the equations, does it?

Comment: $g'=0$ leads to $h_1'(r)h_2(r)-h_1(r)h_2'(r)=0$. And this leads to $\frac{h_1'(r)}{h_2'(r)}=\frac{h_1(r)}{h_2(r)}=g(r)$ or$r-g(r)=0$

Comment: I see. One more question: why is $z(\bar r)=\frac74\bar r$? I tried plugging your value of $\bar r$ in, but can't see how to arrive at that.

Comment: I'm not sure about what I did and will look into it again.